# How can I compile code ClojureScript for use in PhantomJS?

Tags: phantomjs, clojurescript

I'm trying to script PhantomJS in ClojureScript. I'm targeting Node and using phantomjs-node [1]. I have a basic example **working**:

```
(def phantom (js/require "phantom"))
(defn -main [& args]
  (-> phantom
    (.create (fn [browser]
      (-> browser
        (.createPage (fn [page]
          (-> page
            (.open "http://google.com" (fn [status]
              (if (= status "success")
                (-> page (.render "example.png")))
              (-> browser .exit)))))))))))
```

Now, if I use `evaluate` function [2] of PhantomJS webpage object, I the following error:

```
phantom stdout: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: <namespace here>
```

When compiling into JavaScript the code to be evaluated contains the CLJS namespace and hence doesn't properly eval within the context of PhantomJS' webpage object. Here is an example:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (-> phantom
    (.create (fn [browser]
      (-> browser
        (.createPage (fn [page]
          (-> page                                                                                      
            (.open "http://google.com" (fn [status]
              (println (str "opened google? " status))
                (-> page
                  (.evaluate #(-> document .-title)
                    #(do
                      (println (str "Page title is " %))
                      (-> browser .exit))))))))))))))
```

How can I prevent the code to be evaluated within the webpage object of PhantomJS from being namespaced with the CLJS namespace? Or secondly do I have any other options?

- [1] https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node
- [2] http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html

Comment: I don't see `document` variable in your code. Try `js/document` instead of `document`.

Comment: @edbond Woot! That totaly did it. Thanks, plz make this an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `js/document` instead of `document`.
`document` is a reference to clojurescript variable, `js/document` is a document in js world.